# Tomcat started and Home page is working but my web page is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, https

I've been digging up the internet for the solution for this problem but did not find any concrete solution. What I've found is "Switch Location" in server properties and/or changing Server location into "Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation)" but none of these worked for me.

Console in Eclipse during start does not show any problem and always end with suspiciously short server start up. "INFO: Server startup in 7927 ms"

Am I missing some other fix to fix this? Hope you could help me. Thanks a lot in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

To associate the project with the server, right-click the Tomcat server you created in the Server view and select Add and remove projects. Select the service and client projects from the Available projects list and click Add.